# How to Make Macros Stop with Custom Motion?

Tags: functions, macro, error

I am writing a custom Vim motion.  The problem is that when used in a macro (especially at the end of a macro), the macro does not automatically stop when the motion no longer applies.

For example, if I record a macro `I*<Space><Esc>0j` (add `*`  to the start of the line) in register `q`, then `10000@q` would replay the macro until `j` can no longer go to the next line.

In my custom motion, I simply return the same cursor position when the motion does not apply (so the cursor does not move).  However, when this motion is used at the end of a macro, Vim will continuously apply the macro to the same position when the cursor is no longer moving.  How can I modify the function such that the macro can stop automatically when the cursor no longer moves?

My current thinking is maybe the motion can throw some silent exception if the cusor does not move, but I couldn't figure out how to raise an exception silently in a function.

Edit: I think some examples would help.  The following is a minimal (but intentially verbose) example:

```
function! <SID>MoveDown()
    let l:line = line(".")
    exe "norm! :".( l:line+1<=line("$") ? l:line+1 : l:line )."\<CR>"
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>j :call <SID>MoveDown()<CR>
```

Then, `I*<Space><Esc>0<leader>j` would do the same thing as `I*<Space><Esc>0j`, but the former would not stop when it reaches the end of a file (causing multiple `*`  to be inserted) while the latter would.

I have tried doing something like:

```
function! <SID>MoveDown()
    if line(".")==line("$")
        throw "ERROR"
    else
        let l:line = line(".")
        exe "norm! :".( l:line+1<=line("$") ? l:line+1 : l:line )."\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>j :call <SID>MoveDown()<CR>
```

This would indeed cause the macro to stop when EOF is reached, but then the motion throws a big annoying error whenever EOF is reached.  It would be great if it is possible to somehow silence the error message but not the exception itself, but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think it might be hard to give you useful advice without looking at your specific situation. Unfortunately it's not that easy to come up with a generic way to produce an exception or error that will produce the behavior you desire in a macro, so looking at your specific situation might be the best way to give you a useful suggestion.

Comment: @filbranden I added an example, hope it makes my question more clear.